# Impact evaluation: non-traditional regression equation framework

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I have a panel data of households. Meaning I have records of many households over multiple weeks. For the first six weeks no household received any treatment. For next six weeks all households received two treatments A and B. And for last six weeks all households received treatment A only.

I am looking to measure the impact of treatment B only, with respect to first six weeks' outcome, when no-one received any treatment. For the sake of brevity, I am going to refer to first six weeks as "past period", second six weeks as "present period" and last six weeks as "future period".

Suppose $ y_{nit} $ = outcome variable for household i in week t within $n_{th} $ period.

where $ n \in  $ {0, 1, 2}

and 0 = past period, 1 = present period, 2= future period

Let's look at following symbols:

$\bar{y_{ni}}$ = average of $ y_{nit} $ over all t weeks in period n for household i. 
$\bar{\bar{y_{n}}}$ = average of $\bar{y_{ni}} $ over all households in period n.

So, 
$\bar{\bar{y_{1}}} - \bar{\bar{y_{0}}}$ = impact of treatment A and treatment B, with respect to no treatment scenario ,i.e., past period.

$\bar{\bar{y_{1}}} - \bar{\bar{y_{2}}}$ = impact of treatment A only with respect to future period.

and finally, 
($\bar{\bar{y_{1}}} - \bar{\bar{y_{0}}}$) $- $ ($\bar{\bar{y_{1}}} - \bar{\bar{y_{2}}}$) = impact of treatment B with respect to no-treatment scenario, i.e., past period.

The point of having this framework is that the past and future of each household gives the control for their own present. I can easily compute this difference of differences manually. However, I have been thinking of doing it in regression framework. Regression equation is important since I need to control for other covariates too. Sadly, I find that beyond my current ability. The reason is that each household receives the treatments in present and future periods. The only variation is in nature of the treatments over the periods. Therefore I find it impossible to implement any standard form of D-I-D regression models, as their is no "standard" control group which haven't received the treatments in present or future periods.

Is there any compatible regression equation for implementation of such framework? Or are there non-regression ways to carry this analysis?

Eagerly waiting for useful guidance.

Comment: Welcome. In the "future" time period (i.e., last six weeks), do all households receive a second dose of treatment A, or do they just continue receiving treatment A moving forward?

Comment: @ThomasBilach All households receive a second dose of treatment A in future period.